# Limit resizable bounds for other OS X apps' windows

Tags: macos, applescript, desktop, bounds

I'm developing an app that would need to sit below the menu bar. The window would be global but if a window was maximized, I wouldn't want the window to cover my window. Alternately if my window was global I wouldn't want it to cover any other windows.

Is it possible to modify the desktop bounds area available to other apps? I want to disallow other apps from being resized on top of my app's UI.

This would be similar to how you can't expand a window lower than the edges of the Dock or the  Menubar.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in Applescript.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful here, but it DOES directly answer their question. Question was, "Is it possible...".  There is not other clarification needed. It is NOT possible to do this with Applescript.